# jquery ajax form serialization by form name

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, serialization, struts2

I am basically having same form twice ( two same forms with same name and fields, there are no id selectors).This is due to the requirement I am having.

second form, will be displayed on a jquery modal dialog. on submit of save button, form is getting submitted.

Question :

> I DO NOT see form serialized in chrome, firefox , the following is output in console

```
first form actionType=
second form medicalConditionDTO.medicalConditionId=
```

> In IE , I see form serialized

```
LOG: first form
```

actionType=&medicalConditionDTO.medicalConditionId=      &medicalConditionDTO.customerApplicationId=119443   &dataSubmittedSuccessfully=&medicalConditionDTO.name=&__checkbox_medicalConditionDTO.hfRelatedFlg=true

```
LOG: second form
```

actionType=&medicalConditionDTO.medicalConditionId=
&medicalConditionDTO.customerApplicationId=119443&dataSubmittedSuccessfully=&medicalConditionDTO.name=jumbo&medicalConditionDTO.hfRelatedFlg=true&__checkbox_medicalConditionDTO.hfRelatedFlg=true

```
function saveMed() {
    var oForm = document.forms["medicalPopUpForm"];
    console.log("first form " + jQuery(oForm[0]).serialize());
    console.log("second form " + jQuery(oForm[1]).serialize());
    jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '<%=addMedicalURL %>', 
                data: jQuery(oForm[1]).serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    jQuery("#medicalPopup").empty();
                    jQuery("#medicalPopup").html(data);
                    closeDialog();
                }
    });

    return false;
}
```

The code is not working in Chrome, FF as data is not serialized, not coming to the server side.

I really appreciate any help!!!

-Sri

Comment: Unclear what you asking.

Comment: Post your JSP as well.

Answer (score 0):

To make serialize work in chrome,

1. you need to have `id` and `name` both same for `form` tag.
2. you should not have any tags such as `div` or `field set` in the form.
3. All the form elements must have `name` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it. Tested in IE, Chrome.

two ways to achieve this:

1)

```
var oForm = document.getElementsByName("medicalPopUpForm")[1];
console.log("first form " + $(oForm).serialize());
```

2) based on button click, here `d` is "this" variable passed through `onClick` function.

```
var orm = $(d).parents("form");
console.log("second form " + $($(d).parents("form")[0]).serialize());
```